# How do multi-attack powers interact with the Hunting Party power?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Recently, the Ranger in my group started to use this power :

> Hunting Party / Ranger Utility 10
>   Daily ✦ martial, stance
>   Minor Action
>   Personal
>   Effect: Until the stance ends, each time you miss your quarry with an attack, you can choose an ally within 5 squares of the quarry. If that ally hits the quarry before the start of your next turn, the ally's attack deals extra damage equal to your Hunter's Quarry damage.

I've found some answers on the site, like this one: [Do Warlord powers which affect an attack apply both attacks of Twin Strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14638/3548)

But still, my question isn't answered. **If the ranger misses with one attack of Twin Strike and hits with the other, does the miss allow them to grant the Hunting Party bonus to an ally?**

Comment: @BenPlont Please see [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533) for why your comment was removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

The power says when you miss with an *attack*, which is different from missing with a power. Attacks are not powers, instead they are things that you make when you use the power. This also means if you miss with both attacks on Twin Strike, for example, you will trigger *Hunting Party* twice.

Comment: How do you rectify the condition "If that ally hits the quarry". Ally would indicate that's it's another member of the party.

Comment: @BenPlont Yes, that is correct. You apply the effect to your ally, which is not you...I don't understand what you mean by rectify the condition though.

Comment: @firedraco So, even if the hunter hit his Quarry, add the added damage, then misses, you will use Hunting Party on an ally ?

Comment: @Cainam Yes, the ranger can give out the bonus damage from Hunting Party *any* time they miss with a (single-target) attack. This may sound overpowered, especially given how many multi-attack powers ranger have, but rangers 1) don't have much to contribute besides damage, and 2) get a number of their best damage boosts from fighting away from their allies, so in many cases there won't be anyone available to give Hunting Party's bonus to.

Comment: @Cainam To clarify, a multi-*target* attack (with a range of close or area) only counts as a miss if it fails to hit **all** of the targets. A multi-*attack* power determines hit or miss separately for each attack.